# How to publish telegram web to github pages

Tags: npm, gulp, telegram

I have been hacking on [telegram web](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram) and it is pretty awesome.

It is running locally using `gulp watch` but now I want to deploy it to the web, as easily as Igor has done it in his gh-pages: [https://zhukov.github.io/webogram](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram).

It is unclear on how should I do that even though there seems to be `make` scripts for it (there is no mention of it in the README). I tried doing `make publish` but I am getting an error:

```
[01:25:27] Finished 'add-appcache-manifest' after 85 ms
echo -n "Please open http://localhost:8000/dist/index.html and check if everything works fine." && read -e
Please open http://localhost:8000/dist/index.html and check if everything works fine./bin/sh: 1: read: Illegal option -e
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'publish' failed
make: *** [publish] Error 2
```

Here is the publish part of `Makefile`:

```
publish:
    ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js clean
    cd dist && git pull origin gh-pages
    ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js publish
    echo -n "Please open http://localhost:8000/dist/index.html and check if everything works fine." && read -e
    cd dist && git add --all . && git commit -am "merged with master" && git push origin gh-pages
```

Am I doing stuff incorrectly, (like following a very basic procedure of deploying static node apps) or is there something else that is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For lack of better solutions I am posting the hack I made:

I removed the line

```
echo -n "Please open http://localhost:8000/dist/index.html and check if everything works fine." && read -e
```

from my `Makefile` and ran `make publish` and everything worked.

If you are doing it for the first time, you may have to set up the branch `gh-pages` in your remote `origin`:

```
git clone -b gh-pages git@github.com:zhukov/webogram.git dist
git remote set-url origin <your git url>
```

This will clone the branch `gh-pages` into the directory `dist` and set the origin to the correct URL so that you can successfully push your changes.

If you forked Igor's repo, then this is not need as your `origin` will already contain the branch `gh-pages`.